# How to start neo4j service from Debian package?

Tags: debian, neo4j

I'm struggling to install neo4j on Debian after following the instructions at [debian.neo4j.org](http://debian.neo4j.org/) to download the Debian packages.

Neo4j seems to install intself, but after 120 seconds the service fails to start.

#### Failed to start within 120 seconds

Here is the output of apt-get:

```
root@turing:/home/iain# apt-get install neo4j
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  neo4j
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 20 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/37.5 MB of archives.
After this operation, 57.8 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Selecting previously deselected package neo4j.
(Reading database ... 22082 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking neo4j (from .../archives/neo4j_1.9.1_all.deb) ...
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Setting up neo4j (1.9.1) ...
Adding system user `neo4j' (UID 106) ...
Adding new user `neo4j' (UID 106) with group `nogroup' ...
Not creating home directory `/var/lib/neo4j'.
Running in headless (-h) mode
Installing with user neo4j
update-rc.d: using dependency based boot sequencing
WARNING: Max 1024 open files allowed, minimum of 40 000 recommended. See the Neo4j manual.
Using additional JVM arguments:  -server -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -Dorg.neo4j.server.properties=conf/neo4j-server.properties -Djava.util.logging.config.file=conf/logging.properties -Dlog4j.configuration=file:conf/log4j.properties -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled
Starting Neo4j Server...process [21881]... waiting for server to be ready................................................................................................................................. Failed to start within 120 seconds.
Neo4j Server may have failed to start, please check the logs.
invoke-rc.d: initscript neo4j-service, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing neo4j (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
configured to not write apport reports
                                      Errors were encountered while processing:
 neo4j
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

After waiting 120 seconds, the installation fails and the output includes the message "Neo4j server may have failed to start, please check the logs".

#### <strike>Index version has changed and connet be upgraded</strike>

There is a log file at /var/log/neo4j/console.log.

It contains a long Java exception stack trace, but nothing very useful to me.

Most of the exception messaages say something like 'successfully initialized, but failed to start'. Here is an example:

```
Component 'org.neo4j.kernel.extension.KernelExtensions@1d37992' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception.
```

The ultimate cause looks like this:

```
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.impl.storemigration.UpgradeNotAllowedByConfigurationException: Index version (managed by /var/lib/neo4j/data/graph.db/index/lucene-store.db) has changed and cannot be upgraded unless allow_store_upgrade=true is supplied in the configuration
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.index.IndexProviderStore.readRecordsWithNullDefaults(IndexProviderStore.java:133)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.index.IndexProviderStore.<init>(IndexProviderStore.java:65)
        at org.neo4j.index.impl.lucene.LuceneDataSource.newIndexStore(LuceneDataSource.java:299)
        at org.neo4j.index.impl.lucene.LuceneDataSource.start(LuceneDataSource.java:223)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:491)
        ... 20 more
```

The UpgradeNotAllowedByConfigurationException states that "Index version (managed by /var/lib/neo4j/data/graph.db/index/lucene-store.db) has changed and cannot be upgraded unless allow_store_upgrade=true is supplied in the configuration".

I'm trying to install for the first time, not trying to upgrade. I believe I'm using the default configuration determined by the Debian package.

**EDIT:** I worked around this issue. There is a config file `/etc/neo4j/neo4j.properties`. It contains two line that look like this:

```
# Enable this to be able to upgrade a store from 1.4 -> 1.5 or 1.4 -> 1.6
# allow_store_upgrade=true
```

When I uncomment the second line and try to install again, the UpgradeNotAllowedByConfigurationException does not occur.

Installation still fails with a timeout, though.

What can I do to fix the problem and start the neo4j service?

Comment: I've voted to close this because I've started a discussion about my problem on the [Neo4j google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/neo4j/BNOdOChrEKI).

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem before because memory was too small. You first check how many free memory you can use when you run neo4j. It should have at least 300MB for neo4j.

Comment: could you detail your solution a bit more? I am having the same problem